# How do I get jekyll-assets to work with ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick, jekyll

I'm developing a site with Jekyll, where I'm using `jekyll-assets` for caching & asset management of images. I've installed and added `mini_magick` to my plugins in `_config.yml`.

Yet for whatever reason, I *cannot* get any magick commands to execute on any image. In an HTML file, I've tried: `{% asset "header/{{ page.header-img }}" @magick:2x %}` just like the [jekyll-assets documentation](https://github.com/envygeeks/jekyll-assets/tree/v3.0.9#tag--asset--img) dictates. I've also tried `@magick:quality=0.1`, etc. just to see if I can get it to work. No image files are output, except for the image with which I started. Is there something I'm doing wrong? How do I get `ImageMagick` to work with `jekyll-assets`?

Comment: I am not familiar with jekyll. But did you intall Imagemagick? It is needed by mini_magick.

Comment: Yup, installed mini_magick via gem and ImageMagick via Homebrew. Possible it's not in a visible location to Ruby? Not sure

Comment: You could use RMagick rather than mini_magick. I am no expert on either, but does mini_magick work with Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`magick:2x` is not supported anymore, use `magick:double` instead.

You don't need to add `mini_magick` to your plugins, it's a ruby gem, not a jekyll plugin, just add it to your `Gemfile` or do `gem install mini_magick`

Comment: Thanks - the documentation for jekyll-assets absolutely sucks despite how useful a tool it is. Not enough full explanations!

Comment: Yep, it's a nice tool, the documentation could be better.